# How can I solve inequalities like $|3x-5|<x+2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

This is a problem from an advanced mathematics exam book.

 
I'm a bit confused on how to do it because there's an $x$ outside the absolute sign. 
 
I watched a couple of tutorials online and tried solving the problem. Here's what I did: 
$3x-5<x+2$

$3x<x+7$

$2x<7$

$x<7/2$ 

 Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not simply disregard the absolute value sign the way you did. Recall that for all $y$, $|y|=y$ if $y\geq 0$ and $|y|=-y$ if $y<0$. Therefore, you have to get rid of the absolute value sign by considering cases.

Case one: $x\geq \frac{5}{3}$. In this case, $3x-5\geq 0$, hence, the inequality becomes

$$
3x-5<x+2\iff2x<7\iff x<\frac{7}{2}. 
$$

Hence, the inequality is satisfied if $\frac{5}{3}\leq x<\frac{7}{2}$.

Case two: $x<\frac{5}{3}$. In this case, $3x-5<0$, hence, the inequality becomes

$$
-(3x-5)<x+2\iff-3x+5<x+2\iff 3<4x\iff\frac{3}{4}<x.
$$

Thus, the inequality is satisfied if $\frac{3}{4}<x<\frac{5}{3}$.

Combining these two results, you obtain that the inequality is satisfied for all $\frac{3}{4}<x<\frac{7}{2}$.

Comment: Is case one appropriate for this problem?

Comment: No. You break the problem into cases. Both must be considered to solve the problem. Essentially, you only used case one initially, but you must consider both to obtain the complete set of values that satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\lvert u \lvert\lt a \iff -a\lt u\lt a$ where $a\gt 0$. 
Hence $$
\begin{align}
\lvert 3x-5\lvert\lt x+2&\iff 
-x-2\lt 3x-5 \lt x+2\\
&\iff -x+3\lt 3x\lt x+7.\\
\end{align}$$
Now solve the two separate inequalities $3x\lt x+7$ and $-x+3\lt 3x$ along with $x+2\gt0$ and take the intersection of their solution sets.

If you solve the inequalities you get $x\lt 7/2,\;  x\gt3/4$ and $x\gt-2$ respectively. Together we see that the solution is $3/4\lt x\lt 7/2$.